# Getting 'com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException' while updating values from one db to another db

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have two databases connections (broConn and zroConn) and I am updating column values from one table of first DB to respective table of second DB. Both the tables have same schema.

```
String sql = "select * From Personal_Info";
stmt = broConn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next())
{
    String sql1 = "UPDATE personal_info SET Score = ?, Result = ?,
           ModifiedBy = ?, ModifiedDate = ?, StartDate = ?,
               EndDate = ?, UploadState = ?" + " WHERE CandidateID = ?";

    stmt = zroConn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    stmt.setInt(1, rs.getInt(8));
    stmt.setString(2, rs.getString(9));
    stmt.setString(3, rs.getString(15));
    stmt.setDate(4, rs.getDate(16));
    stmt.setDate(5, rs.getDate(17));
    stmt.setDate(6, rs.getDate(18));
    stmt.setString(7, rs.getString(19));
    stmt.setInt(8, rs.getInt(1));
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);
}
```

I am getting below error in stacktrace -

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, Result = ?, ModifiedBy = ?, ModifiedDate = ?, StartDate = ?, EndDate = ?, Upl' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1540)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2595)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1468)
    at com.company.testdata.UpdateZRODB.main(UpdateZRODB.java:72)
```

Comment: Take a _sout_ of your full query including the values and put it here.

Comment: `UploadState = ?"`

Comment: `System.out.println(query)` put the output here

Comment: @JohnJoe - UploadState is a String value.

Comment: @Roshana: I am getting below value after putting 'System.out.println(rs);'
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@19e1023e

Comment: @JayeshB still get the same error ?

Comment: Is your table called `Personal_Info` or `personal_info`? And why don't you call an update directly onto your table without selecting data first?

Comment: Yes, the ResultSet (rs) is giving the output correctly, but the error is coming while updating the table in other database.

Comment: @NicoHaase It is Personal_Info, but I suppose the lower case won't create any problem. I still changed it, but getting the same error. I am actually getting the selected columns data from table1 of first DB and updating it to the respective columns of table1 of second DB.

Comment: I changed line 'stmt.executeUpdate(sql1);' to 'stmt.executeUpdate();' and it resolved the issue. Thank you all.